# Multiple conditional assignment of same type - Performance concerns

Tags: c++

We have a code base where a dev implemented following conditional assignment. Essentially all four conditions (`condition2`) check for the same thing (say `i==j`) and is written as follows

```
    ....
    else if (condition1){
        a = condition2 ? m : 0;
        b = condition2 ? 0 : m;
        c = condition2 ? n : 0;
        d = condition2 ? 0 : n;
```

While this looks compact (and more readable? not sure about this), I am of view that making them into a if else statement as this would save doing the same if check 4 times and improve performance. Is the existing approach advisable or rewriting to a single if else advisable?

Comment: Check the generated assembly with optimizations turned on; depending on the condition, the compiler might well be able to make both versions behave identically.

Comment: The pythonic way: `std::tie(a,b,c,d)= condition2? std::tuple{m,0,n,0}: std::tuple{0,m,0,n};`

Comment: Not sure why the question is closed. The purpose was purely not about style but more about performance itself. Accepted answer proves that compiler is smart enough to group them together.

Comment: @NathanPierson But unless your coding for a specific compiler and compiler version, I'm not sure why you would want to make any decisions based on how one specific compiler version handled it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, the question was about whether the change would improve performance. If you go strictly by what the standard says, independent of actual implementations, there's not really anything to say. Pointing out that in practice compilers are able to optimize it to the logically equivalent version that evaluates `condition2` fewer times actually conveys information.

Comment: @NathanPierson Right, but that's an argument based on what compilers generally do and not based on the behavior of one particular compiler. If there was a question about whether taller people generally have larger shoe sizes, "find a tall person and ask them" is not really a helpful suggestion because the question is about tall people generally. (At least, not without clearly explaining how the data point should be used.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the compiler will figure out what's best for execution. As a programmer you should focus on readability.

For example, your code with -O3 optimization results in `condition2` being evaluated only once. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/4fs8efjoa

If your goal is micro-optimization, you could in theory avoid branching altogether by re-writing your code like this:

```cpp
    ...
    else if (condition1) {
        int c2 = condition2, n2 = 1 - c2;
        a = c2 * m;
        b = n2 * m;
        c = c2 * n;
        d = n2 * n;
    }
```

It has no branches on `condition2`, but is harder to understand. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/ojrP9rf5s. (NB: multiplication instructions are expensive, but are less expensive than branch mispredictions.)

**UPDATE:**

Surprisingly, the code posted by @Red.Wave in the comments:

```cpp
    ...
    else if (condition1) {
        std::tie(a, b, c, d) =
            condition2 ? std::tuple{m, 0, n, 0} : std::tuple{0, m, 0, n};
    }
```

results in the same assembly output as your original code with -O3 optimization. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/YMMbYPbrj

**UPDATE:**

And for completeness' sake, since `a` <-> `b`, and `c` <-> `d` are complementary to each other, you could also do this:

```cpp
    ...
    else if (condition1) {
        a = condition2 ? m : 0;
        b = m - a;
        c = condition2 ? n : 0;
        d = n - c;
    }
```

See here: https://godbolt.org/z/Khr8zfKMq

Comment: Not sure I'd want to introduce a bunch of multiplications into my assembly

Comment: Me neither. I am just saying there is a way to avoid branching. On assembly level `imul` takes 3 CPU clock IIRC, which is still less expensive than branching.

Comment: Thanks for the compiler link. Even with `-O1`, the conditional assignment seems to be grouped to one if check.

Comment: @AndyG: If you don't mind restricting it to 2's complement machines, you can avoid multiplication pretty easily. Assuming `condition2` is Boolean, `-condition2` will change it from 0/1 to 0/-1. So `x & -condition2` will give either 0 or x. `a = m & -condition2; b = m & -!condition2; c = n & -condition2; d = n & -~condition2;`. But as already noted, most will find this completely unreadable.

Comment: @AndyG: I could, *perhaps*, see allowing it under one circumstance: as an emulation of an N-bit 1-2 demultiplexer in code that was supposed to emulate logic at the gate level. Other than a somewhat oddball way of propagating a single selector line to multiple bits, that's pretty much how a real demultiplexer actually works. But for most reasonably normal code, no definitely not.